# Do action in view controller after alert view

Tags: iphone, uialertview, nsnotificationcenter

On launch of the application, I may show an alert view from the view controller shown on launch. If the user doesn't click the cancel button in this alert view, I need to do an action in another view controller.

How will I accomplish this? I thought of using `NSNotificationCenter` to add an observer in the view controller which will perform the action. Then, from the current view controller, I will post a notification. Problem is, as this alert view is shown on launch, I don't know where to add the observer for the notification as `viewDidLoad:` is not called in the view controller yet.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the delegate of the alert view wherever you're creating it and then implement:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

If `buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex` then you should do your action.

Comment: Problem is, that I will need to change the selected tab in my tab bar controller. This is easily accomplished, but I also need to call a method in the new view controller. So, when `buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex` I will change the tab bar and call a method in the view controller I just changed to.

Comment: Then have a reference to the view controller on that tab (can get at it through the tab controller's `viewController` property if you want) and call a method on it.

Comment: Of course. I should have thought about that. Getting the view controller through tab bar controller is no problem. Thank you very much for your help!